# Função asset não funciona no Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, twig

Instalei o Symfony 5 utilizando o comando `$ composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name` com a intenção de obter o pacote mais completo possível do Symfony.

Após configurar meu Controller e as rotas, iniciei a codificação do template Twig fazendo uso do Bootstrap 4 via CND e a renderização da página funcionou normalmente.

Quando decidi configurar os arquivos do Bootstrap no meu local e não mais via CDN, percebi que a função `asset()` não retornava o caminho dos arquivos armazenados na pasta "public".

O mesmo ocorre com outros arquivos e diretórios localizados dentro da pasta "public".

Verifeiquei meu arquivo "composer.json" e o asset está configurado na seguinte versão: `"symfony/asset": "5.1.*"`. O mesmo se encontra corretamente instalado na pasta "vendor".

Segue um exemplo de uso da função no meu código no arquivo "base.html.twig":

```
href="{{ asset("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css") }}
```

Refiz os passos de instalação do componente "asset" seguinto as instruções da documentação abaixo e também não obtive resultado:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou pelo mesmo e se possui alguma solução para o mesmo.

Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri a solução para essa questão por acaso:

O erro estava relacionado ao modo como eu executava o servidor PHP. Eu estava executando diretamenta no diretório `public/`.

Dentro de `public/`, executava o seguinte comando:

```
$php -S localhost:8000
```

De modo geral, o sisteme construído em Symfony funcionava normalmente, menos o método `asset()` (só percebi essa única falha).

Como solução, bastou acessar o diretório principal do projeto e executar o servidor utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

Gostaria que alguém complementasse a resposta com uma informação teórica sobre como isso corrige a falha, pois sou iniciante e meu conhecimento sobre servidores é limitado.